# How to effectively search laws?

Tags: international, legal-education

A common answer to problems and situations includes *researching your state/country's law* to check what are the consequences of a particular action.

As a layman, it is difficult to do this research effectively, since it's hard to find a comprehensive resource/channel of this information, and Legislative Language is complex and very structured.

Is there a method I can consistently apply for *most* political regions (Country or State) in order to do this research, and efficiently find what I'm looking for?

Comment: All Australian laws (Commonwealth and all States & Territories) are available at www.austlii.edu.au

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on *what you're looking for*.  For example, if you want the details of a specific regulation or the statutory definition of some term, the internet is pretty good!  If you can't follow legal language, or if you want to know whether something is *legal*, you probably have to hire a lawyer.

In general you can't effectively determine the legality or legal consequences of an action: As noted in [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/1196/10), even the *enumeration* of laws is an unsolved problem.  But you can look for "safe harbors" ... if you know in which statutes or case law you are likely to find them.

This is one reason we can't just [kill all the lawyers](http://www.enotes.com/shakespeare-quotes/lets-kill-all-lawyers) ;)